# How do I run a regex replace on all elements of a list of Strings in HQL?

Tags: java, string, list, hql, regex-replace

I have the query:

`@Query("SELECT t FROM thing t WHERE t.code in :codes") public List<Thing> getThingsByCodeList(@Param("codes") List<String> codes);`

and now I need to ignore hyphens in the query so I remove all the hyphens from `t.codes` like:

`@Query("SELECT t FROM thing t WHERE regexp_replace(t.code, '-', '') in :codes") public List<Thing> getThingsByCodeList(@Param("codes") List<String> codes);`

but I am unsure how to also remove the hyphens from all Strings in the List `codes`

I know I can remove the hyphens before calling the method but I want to make sure this solution is impossible first.